# cannot connect internet via wifi or lan but via android mobile bluetooth tethering

Tags: networking, internet, bluetooth, dns, android

After updating my Linux OS i could connect to internet by my android Bluetooth tethering but an not connect to internet by WiFi or LAN, so i have tried to find out how it could be possible?

my resolvconf setting when contented via tethering  is:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.44.1
```

and those for wifi are:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

i have also added the **/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d** file like this:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

but when i do `sudo resolvconf -u` the **nameserver 192.168.1.1** dont pasted in the **/etc/resolv.conf ** files.

My guesses is that the problem is from missing the **nameserver 192.168.1.1** which is my modem IP.

**Update:**

I have changed the  **/etc/resolv.conf** like this:

```
# Generated by Connection Manager
#nameserver 127.0.0.1
#nameserver ::1
#nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

So could you explain why this happened?

thanks.